# djangoの"<{0}>"は何を意味するのか？

Tags: python, django

djangoを使ったソースコードに"<{0}>"がありました。
{0}は知っているのですが、<>をつける理由がわかりません。
この<>は文字列として認識されていませんでした。

```
for h in Hello.objects.all(): print(h.your_name)
```

とした時、<>が含まれていなかったのでそう考えました。
ある種のタプルのようなものかなと考えています。
しかし、ネットで検索しても見つかりません。
うまく説明ができないのでソースコードを貼っておきます。
https://eiry.bitbucket.io/tutorials/tutorial/models.html
を参考にしました。

```
from django.db import models
class Hello(models.Model):
    your_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return "<{0}>".format(self.your_name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ただの文字ですよ。

> <>が含まれていなかったのでそう考えました。

Helloクラスの `__str__` メソッドですから、Helloのインスタンスを文字列化する時に使われるものです。
確かめるなら、

```
for h in Hello.objects.all():
    print(h)
```

です。

---

https://eiry.bitbucket.io/tutorials/tutorial/models.html#id12

ここで、`Hello.objects.all()`でlistに格納されたHelloのインスタンスを表示したとき、`<>`が2重に付いていますね。

Djangoの`Model`の`__repr__`メソッドは
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L512

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)
```

こうなっています。`<クラス名: クラスの文字列表現>` という表示です。

Helloのインスタンスを`repr(h)`で表示すると`<Hello: <Kenji>>`のようになっていますが、この内側の `<>` が、質問の `return "<{0}>".format(self.your_name)` に付いている `<>` です。